# How to change special characters hotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotkeys

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `2` inserts a Zero Width Non-Joiner character (`U+200C`). I want to make my favorite `Ctrl` + `Space` combination do it instead.

Is it possible to do that?

I prefer not to use a third-party application like `AutoHotKey`.

Comment: Minus a third-party application, likely the only way to do this would be to modify the Windows registry directly.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks. do you have any more tips on that?

Comment: I have never needed to use it personally, but you might have luck with Googling [modify keyboard keys in the windows registry](https://www.google.com/search?q=modify+keyboard+keys+in+the+windows+registry). It seemed to turn up some articles on the topic that may be helpful.